# Backup SQL Server 2008 diagrams

Tags: sql, diagrams

how can I backup the SQL Server 2008 diagrams ?
I need to move some diagrams from data base to another has the same tables and everything but has more stored procedures , functions and so on ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175868.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Copying a table from one database diagram to another diagram adds a reference to the table in the second diagram. The table is not duplicated in your database. For example, if you copy the authors table from one database diagram to another, each diagram references the same authors table in the database.

**[To copy a table from another database diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175868.aspx)**

> Make sure you are connected to the
>   database whose table you want to copy.
>
> Open the source and target database
>   diagrams and within the source
>   diagram, select the table that you
>   want to copy to the target diagram.
>
> Click the Copy button on the toolbar.
>   This action places the selected table
>   definition on the Clipboard.
>
> Switch to the target diagram. This
>   diagram must be in the same database
>   as the source diagram.
>
> Click the Paste button on the toolbar.
>   The Clipboard contents appear at the
>   new location and remain highlighted
>   until you click elsewhere. If
>   relationships exist between the
>   selected tables and other tables in
>   the target diagram, relationship lines
>   are automatically drawn.
>
> When you edit the table in either
>   diagram, your changes are reflected in
>   both diagrams. Similarly, once you
>   save the table in either diagram, the
>   table is no longer considered
>   "modified" in either diagram.

Comment: Can you add the link you used? Seems fair to link to it rather than copy/paste.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer Sudantha but can I take the diagrams from the old database to a file and then import it to the new data base which has the same structure like the old one ?

Comment: Can anyone my friends help me to copy the SQL Server Diagrams from database to another one with the same structure and tables ?